# How can I backup mongodb database regularly, the specific time of a day

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, cron

I want to backup database regularly in my linux server (Ubuntu 12.02),

I red some documents and that saying I should use linux cron, and Fortunately, I found this : https://github.com/micahwedemeyer/automongobackup/blob/master/src/automongobackup.sh

I put my configuration and save it `mongobackup.sh` and put it to `/etc/cron.daily`

It was 3 days ago, Today, I check the backup folder(`/var/backups/mongodb`) but the backup file does not exist.

Should I detele extension of `mongobackup.sh`? or something I missed?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your **mongobackup.sh** doesn't have proper rights to be executed.

`chmod 755 /etc/cron.daily/mongobackup.sh` should do the trick, but it wouldn't hurt to see what's inside of the script and results of `ls -l /etc/cron.daily`.

Also, you could manually add a task to root crontab (or any other user that **has rights** to run the script and to work with everything mentioned there):
to start editing crontab enter command `crontab -u username -e`
in the end of the file insert this: `0 0 * * * /bin/sh /full-path-to-mongobackup.sh >/dev/null 2>&1`, press `Esc`, `:wq`, `Enter` - that will create a task, which will run **mongobackup.sh** every midnight.

And in order to answer your question about how you could run scripts in specific time of a day i would recommend you to read [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) about **cron** and **crontab**.